# Difference between DDR1 and DDR2?

Tags: linux, memory

What is the difference? I just purchased a dedicated server (Dell 2.4GHz Intel Xeon - 4GB Ram - 74GB SCSI 10k RPM) with DDR1 but I was looking for DDR2, will I see a difference?

Answer (score 4):

DDR2 is roughly twice the speed of DDR(1) and as stated they are designed specifically to not be cross compatible - both physically and electrically.

Let us know the exact details of the server and we'll try to let you know if you've been ripped off or not - DDR(1) is a very old technology.

Comment: DDR is usually 400Mhz (you don't see slower frequencies than that anymore, but they do exist)
DDR2 can be anywhere from 533Mhz to 1200Mhz, and can be overclocked further.

Comment: Really old DDR2 modules (pre 2004) can in practice be slower than DDR modules due to the higher latency. If you want to compare DDR with DDR2 modules it easier to go for the Peak Transfer Rate than the frequency. For example PC2-6400 tells you it's a DDR2 module and it can manage 6400 MBi/s. It's about twice the speed of a PC-3200 module.

Answer (score -1):

They're incompatible.  If your server takes DDR1 then you can't install DDR2 or DDR3.  The difference you see will only be in your wallet or budget.

Comment: There is a difference in speed.